# how i can mock view model to use compose preview?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-compose-preview

I have a MainScreen composable being injected with a viewmModel using hilt.

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    viewModel: MainScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {}
```

The problem is that I cannot use this in the preview because will not generate viewModel using hilt

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    AlbumExpoTheme {
        MainScreen()
    }
}
```

how can I go around this so I can use the preview?

Error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewModels creation is not supported in Preview
```